# C gethostbyaddr returns NULL

Tags: c, sockets

I'm really a beginner with C and sockets. I know I shouldn't use gethostbyaddr by this is for an exam so I have to use what they tell me to use... 
I'm using this code from a Linux machine (Ubuntu 14.04).

I'm trying to write an echo c/s program. All works fine but when I try to have some info about the client from my server, `struct hostent * clienthost` is null.

This is my server.c:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in cliaddr, servaddr;
    struct hostent * clienthost;
    int port, sd, len;
    char request[MAX_LENGTH];
    const int on = 1;

    port = atoi(argv[1]);

    memset ((char *)&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;  
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(port);

    sd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(on));
    bind(sd,(struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    for (;;)
    {
        len = sizeof(request);
        recvfrom(sd, request, sizeof(request), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &len);

        clienthost = gethostbyaddr( (char *) &cliaddr.sin_addr, sizeof(cliaddr.sin_addr), AF_INET);
        if (clienthost == NULL) 
            printf("client host information not found\n");
        else 
            printf("Operation from: %s %i\n", clienthost->h_name,(unsigned)ntohs(cliaddr.sin_port));

        sendto(sd, &request, sizeof(request), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, len);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the client have a DNS entry - if not put one in `/etc/hosts` for testing

Comment: are you sure the address in question actually has a PTR record?  If something goes wrong it will return NULL and set `h_errno` with the error.  check out `man gethostbyaddr`  for more info.  My guess is you are looking up the IP address and are getting a host not found.. you can verify by doing `host ip.address.of.client` or `dig -x ip.address.of.client` and see what you get. (Assuming you are using dns)

Comment: @EdHeal you are right. In my defense, my teacher didn't mention that it won't work but of course I should have understood it by myself :D

Comment: Put in an entry into /etc/hosts then the function should work and return something for that IP address

Comment: @EdHeal yes I did it works perfectly :)

Comment: Your welcome (you can use it to do testing of web sites as well and preventing MS$ checking up on you)

Comment: When calling `recvfrom()`, `len = sizeof(request);` needs to be `len = sizeof(cliaddr);` instead. And you need to check the return value of `recvfrom()` for success before calling `gethostbyaddr()`, otherwise you will be passing garbage to it.

Comment: thank you @RemyLebeau for the len mistake! I removed from the code all the checks to make a better readable question, but I'm checking for the success of recvfrom() :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the client have a DNS entry - if not put one in `/etc/hosts` for testing
                    – Ed Heal